# Windows 10 right clicking on files refreshes the file explorer

Tags: windows-10

How to fix right clicking in flies like txt, docx, png the file explorer refreshes and no menu were shown.

When i right click on exe files and shortcuts and folders it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have accidentially installed a program that have installed a handler for txt, docx, png and such, and this handler fails to load.

I would suggest trying to figure out when this started happening, track down which software was installed at that time (the install date is noted in the installation list inside "Settings" - "System" - "Apps and functions") and uninstall that software and see if the problems clear.

Comment: I remember it started when I installed Virtual Machine and allowed drag and drop from host to virtual machine. I need this VM for now.

Comment: @quickbrownfox I would suggest exporting the VM image (your actual virtual machine) to a safe medium, and then uninstall the VM host application. If the problem clears, you know whats causing it. Then you can reinstall VM and restore the VM image, confidently knowing what the problem stems from.